# GitHub for Mac throw a Git Error when I clicked the Publish button

Tags: macos, git, configuration, github

Like the Title, it throw me a Git Error message:

```
2013-06-08 13:51:35.249 GitHub for Mac Login[1883:707] AskPass with
arguments: (
    "/Applications/GitHub.app/Contents/MacOS/GitHub for Mac Login",
    "root@192.168.1.107's password: " )
2013-06-08 13:51:35.285 GitHub for Mac Login[1883:707] Error reading 
attributes for password: OSStatus 840183217 
Counting objects: 3, done. 
Writing objects:  33% (1/3)
Writing objects:  66% (2/3)
Writing objects: 100% (3/3)   
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 215 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0) 
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent     
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
 To root@192.168.1.107:/var/www/html/repository/  ! [remote rejected]
 master -> master (branch is currently checked out) error: failed to
 push some refs to 'root@192.168.1.107:/var/www/html/repository/'  (1)
```

I'm a beginner of use git to control the program version, and I find something like GitHub for Mac to use easily.
What I should be in the linux server configuration?
I find some useful from
http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/
How to publish files to my server?
Thank you!

Comment: What is the command you are executing when you get that error?

Comment: An app called GitHub for Mac. It throw me this message when I clicked the Publish button with a test file.

Comment: I have formatted the output for you. Next time, try to be more careful when copying the output so that it is easier to read. And use the *Code Sample* (Ctrl-K) function, not *Block quote*.

Comment: Thanks. I will do it next time.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that you are trying to `push` to a non-bare repository, i.e. a normal repository rather than one that was created (with `git init --bare`) to enable it to function easily as a "central" repository that can be pushed to.

If you want more guidance on how to get started with git, take a look at the question
[Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Comment: It looks difficult, and thank you very mush. I give it a try.